# Select thumbnails with PDFjs

Tags: javascript, jquery

After upload a pdf i show with PDF.js a thumbnails and work it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if (!PDFJS.workerSrc && typeof document !== 'undefined') {
              // workerSrc is not set -- using last script url to define default location

              PDFJS.workerSrc = (function () {
                'use strict';
                var scriptTagContainer = document.body ||
                                         document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                var pdfjsSrc = scriptTagContainer.lastChild.src;
                return pdfjsSrc && pdfjsSrc.replace(/\.js$/i, '.worker.js');
              })();

              PDFJS.workerSrc = 'pdfjs-dist-master/build/pdf.worker.js';
            }

        $("#pdfInp").change(function () {
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    showInCanvas(e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        });

        function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
            var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
            var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
            var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
            var raw = window.atob(base64);
            var rawLength = raw.length;
            var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

            for (i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
                array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return array;
        }

        function showInCanvas(url) {
            // See README for overview
            'use strict';
            // Fetch the PDF document from the URL using promises
            var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary(url);
            PDFJS.getDocument(pdfAsArray).then(function (pdf) {

                // Using promise to fetch the page
// Get div#container and cache it for later use
var container = document.getElementById("container");

// Loop from 1 to total_number_of_pages in PDF document    
for (var i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i++) {

    // Get desired page
    pdf.getPage(i).then(function(page) {

      var scale = .3;
      var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
      var div = document.createElement("div");

      // Set id attribute with page-#{pdf_page_number} format
      div.setAttribute("id", "page-" + (page.pageIndex + 1));

      // This will keep positions of child elements as per our needs
      //div.setAttribute("style", "position: relative");
       div.setAttribute("class", "page");

      // Append div within div#container
      container.appendChild(div);

      // Create a new Canvas element
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

      // Append Canvas within div#page-#{pdf_page_number}
      div.appendChild(canvas);

      var node = document.createElement("p");
      var textnode = document.createTextNode("pagina " + (page.pageIndex + 1));
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      div.appendChild(node);


      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;

      var renderContext = {
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport
      };

      // Render PDF page
      page.render(renderContext);
    });
}//END LOOP

            });
        }
    });
```

But i want select a multiple thumbnail show it. I think possible with the class css. This the code

```
$.fn.seleziona = function() {
var menuSel = $(this);
menuSel.find('.page').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('open');
    }
  });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#container").seleziona();
});
```

end not work. That code worked only the DOM be present before the upload

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution to this iastimo?